# Trying to get sockets with the same address and different ports to pass data back and forth

Tags: c, multicast, ports

Firstly, please excuse my probable butchering the technical terminology. I've been thrown into socket IO with little formal education and I know that I am bungling words left and right.

I'm trying to build a client and server in C that enables multiple clients to connect to one another. The general procedure goes something like this:

1) Server has one port that is constantly listening and accepting connections
2) A client connects on that port
3) Server creates a new socket (same address, different port number), tells the client to connect to that socket, and closes the connection with the client.
4) The client connects to the designated socket and provides the server with a channel it would like to be on
5) Server places that socket on the designated channel
6) Repeat steps 2 through 5 for each client that connects to the server
/* all of the above has been coded already */
7) Once a channel has 2 or more members, I'd like to have each member port be able to broadcast to all other ports in the same channel (and thus the clients communicate with each other)

In this situation, all involved sockets on the same channel have the same address and DIFFERENT port numbers. Everything I've read and researched about broadcasting and multicasting revolves around each communicator having the same port number and different addresses.

Is there a way to do the communication that I'm hoping to do, in C?

Comment: I'm thinking the client will have to tell the server to broadcast something

Comment: So broadcasting is the way to go? Is there a specific type of broadcasting or variation of common code that I need?

Comment: You don't need anything specific - just have the server loop through all connected clients and send whatever message to each of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you want to use the listen() and accept() functions for TCP.  You can do what you describe and have clients talk to each other, but all traffic will run through the server as a hub.

If you want all clients to be able to talk to every other client, you have a few options:

1. Server is the hub for all data and passes it between clients for you
2. Clients maintain direct connections to the other clients and pass data to each other in order to facilitate the hub.  This means lots of data copying.
3. Broadcast or multicast (UDP).  This is only possible over a local network, as internet routers will block multicast and broadcast traffic.

I would probably go with #1.

Comment: There's no way to have two sockets, with the same address and different port numbers, communicate with each other?

Comment: not directly: a socket represents a pair of (source,dest).  You can't reconfigure the destination on the fly, or communicate with more than one destination.  TCP is reliable and involves an under layer which handles retransmissions and the like, so in general, multicast and broadcast does not work with TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that each client has it's own IP address, so for a client to communicate with another client, and not involving the server, it would need to open a new connection with the other client, send data and then close the connection.  While doable, I do not think this idea would scale very well.

I do agree with Syplex that having the server act as a relay hub is probably the best, and certainly has the potential to scale well.  So the data-flow would be something like this:

- a client receives a message that is to be retransmitted to all the other clients.
- this message is passed to all other instances of your server process
- each of these instances of your server process sends out the message.

The issue becomes how you are implementing you server, and you do have two models that fit what you describe:

(1) you are using a multi-treaded server, in which each new connection causes a thread to be spawned to handle the communication between the client and the server.

(2) you are using a forking server, in which the server forks a new process to communicate with the client.

In case (1) you would be interested in intra-process communication (message queue for example) while in case (2) you would be interested in inter-process communication (named pipes or shared memory for example).

At this point there are two many variables to give a concise answer.  I hope this helps gets you started and at least gives you somewhere to start looking.

Comment: I'm forking off a new process for each client and had arrived at the same conclusions (pipes or shared memory: this would be the server acting as the relay hub, right?). However, if the sockets with different port numbers could communicate, that would cut out the server middleman from the data flow.

Comment: Yep, the server acts as a middle-man.  And yes it would be nice if the "sockets with different port numbers could communicate", it would reduce data flow, and make the logic of your program easier.  However, as others have said, this is not how sockets work.  Glad we could be of help